# C#, escape double quote not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to escape quotes in an xpath string like so:

```
var mktCapNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=""yfs_j10_a""]");
```

The actual string I want passed is:

```
//*[@id="yfs_j10_a"]
```

This gives a compiler errors: `) expected` and `; expected`

I'm sure it's simple but I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use the escape char '\':

```
"//*[@id=\"yfs_j10_a\"]"
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to make this a verbatim string to use the `""` as an escape

```
@"//*[@id=""yfs_j10_a""]"
```

For a normal string literal you need to use backslashes to escape the double quotes

```
"//*[@id=\"yfs_j10_a\"]"
```

Comment: Or escape the quotes like so:  "//*[@id=\"yfs_j10_a\"]" but the verbatim string is easier to read (just mentioning it so you know the possibilities).

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@` prefix to your string.

```
@"//*[@id=""yfs_j10_a""]"
```

or escape the quotes with a `\`

```
"//*[@id=\"yfs_j10_a\"]"
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# the \ character is used to escape (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)).
This is different from VB where there are no escape characters except "" which escapes to ".

This means in C# you do not need vbCrLf to start a new line or vbTab to add a tab character to a string.  Instead use "\r\n" and "\t".

You can also make the string a literal using the @ character, but I do not think this works with the quotation mark.